# Choice of parameter for the solution to a PDE, method of characteristics.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

There are a couple of questions I have which would help me understand the working (I have put the questions in bold).

*Question:* Find the solution to the partial differential equation

$$uu_x-u_y=2, \qquad y \gt 0$$

Subject to the initial condition $u(x,0)=x^2$ and determine where in the xy-plane this solution is valid.

*My attempt:*

Parameterise the initial data:

$$x = s, \qquad y = 0, \qquad u = x^2$$

Write the differential equations which determine the characteristics:

$$\frac{dx}{d\tau}=u, \qquad \frac{dy}{d\tau}=-1, \qquad \frac{du}{d\tau}=2.$$

**1. Are the above called 'Characteristics', or are the 'solutions' to the differential equations called the characteristics of the PDE? For example. solving the third equation, $\bf{u = 2\tau+s^2}$.**

Solving the ordinary differential equations, and eliminating $\tau$ I get the family of ground/base curves, in terms of the parameter, $s$:

$$x=y^2 - s^2y +s$$

**2. Does this answer the part of the question 'determine where in the xy-plane this solution is valid.'?**

Now to find the solution, since $y = -\tau, $ we just need to find an expression for $s$:

Using the quadratic formula for the equation corresponding to the family of base curves, I get:
$$s = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1-4y(x-y^2)}}{2y}$$

**3. I don't know which sign I should choose for the problem and the initial conditions given?**

Finally the solution to the partial differential equation is going to be:
$$u(x,y) = u = -2y+s^2.$$ - Where $s$ would be one of the two possible solutions above.

**4. Is this correct?**

**5. Are there any resources which would assist my understanding of simple PDE's?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, your result is :
$$u(x,y) = -2y+\left(\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1-4y(x-y^2)}}{2y}\right)^2.$$
These solutions both satisfy the PDE $uu_x-u_y=2$. But both doesn't agree with the condition $u(x,0)=x^2$.

So, you are right to ask about the sign of the square root.

If the sign is plus, obviously $u$ tends to infinity for $y$ tending to $0$, which contradicts the condition. This solution of the PDE must be rejected.

If the sign is minus, $u$ tends to $x^2$ for $y$ tending to $0$. This is easy to show thanks to limited series expansion. I let this for you.

Thus, the solution satisfying the PDE and the boundary condition is :
 $$u(x,y) = -2y+\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4y(x-y^2)}}{2y}\right)^2.$$